# Sinusoidal tone in Signal-to-Noise measurements

Tags: speech-processing, snr

Mengapa kita menggunakan nada uji sinusoidal saat mengukur signal-to-noise pada saluran bicara daripada hanya sinyal ucapan itu sendiri ?

**EDIT**: Translation from Indonesian according to Google:

Why do we use a sinusoidal test tone when measuring the signal-to-noise of the speech channel rather than just the speech signal itself?

Comment: i'm not sure that i agree with the premise to the question.

Comment: I’m afraid I'll have to vote to close this question because it asks for a reason for something that isn't true. Sadly, there's nothing to answer here. You usually wouldn't use a sinusoidal tone to judge the quality of a speech channel.